# Anydice: a pool where stress dice cancel out action dice of equal or lower value and return the number and value of action dice remaining in the pool?

Tags: statistics, dice, anydice

I've seen a couple of other posts with similar but distinctly different dice canceling mechanics so I figured I would ask for a hand.

The mechanic is this:

> Players roll a pool of Xd6 Action dice and Yd6 Stress dice

Stress dice of equal or greater value than action dice will cancel each other out, removing both dice from the pool and should do so beginning with the highest values and continue in descending order. Each stress die may only cancel out a single action die and any remaining stress dice that have a lower value than the lowest action die are discarded. Action dice that remain are used for the player's turn.

ex.

> player 1 has a pool of 5 action dice and 3 stress dice.

> player 1 rolls 6, 5, 4, 3, 3 action and 5, 4, 2 stress

> player 1 uses 5 stress to cancel 5 action and 4 stress to cancel 4 action, all 4 dice are discarded; there are no action dice with value 2 or lower, so the 2 stress is also discarded

> player 1 is left with 3 action dice: 6, 3, 3

I’d love for it to end up with a result that told me how many action dice are left and what the values of those dice are as I change the number of action and stress dice in the pool, but really anything that shows this mechanic would be a big help.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, Erbrakaderbra! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: Ok. I’m 3 hours and 6 drinks into an airline lounge so I can give the complete answer. What you need is two sequences passed to a function. Build a third sequence. Work down the action sequence till you get to the highest stress number. Then work down the stress sequence knocking out action dice. Return the third sequence.

Comment: that sounds similar to one of the other forum results i found, and im trying to understand and tweak it for this application but i dont think i really know enough to know if its doing anything useful! haha


this is what i am currently working with but it only has 2 sequences and im not sure where to go from here.. it seems to return more or less expected results when dealing with 1d6 vs 1d6.


function: actionroll ACTION:s STRESS:s
{
 loop X over {1..#ACTION}
 {
  if X@STRESS >= X@ACTION {result: 0}
  else {result: X@ACTION}
 }
}

output [actionroll 1d6 1d6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script using my [Icepool Python library](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool). Rather than considering entire sets of rolls at once, Icepool uses the strategy of updating a running total based on how many dice in each pool rolled each number.

```
import icepool
from icepool import d6, EvalPool

class AllActionStress(EvalPool):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, action, stress):
        # This is called for each possible outcome 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
        # with the number of action and stress dice that rolled that number.
        # This method uses this information to update a "running total".
        
        # action_set: The set of surviving action dice.
        # leftover_stress: The number of surviving stress dice that rolled 
        # this number or higher.
        action_set, leftover_stress = state or ((), 0)
        leftover_stress += stress
        if leftover_stress >= action:
            leftover_stress -= action
        else:
            action -= leftover_stress
            action_set += (outcome,) * action
            leftover_stress = 0
        
        return action_set, leftover_stress
    
    def final_outcome(self, final_state, *pools):
        # Just return the action set; any remaining stress is ignored.
        return final_state[0]
    
    def direction(self, *_):
        # See outcomes in descending order.
        return -1

all_action_stress = AllActionStress()
result = all_action_stress.eval(d6.pool(5), d6.pool(3))

# The number of surviving action dice.
# If this is all you are interested in, it would be more efficient to only 
# count the number of surviving action dice in AllActionStress, rather than 
# computing the entire surviving action sets and counting the length at the
# end as we do here.
print(result.sub(len))
```

Denominator: 1679616

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1097586 | 65.347437% |
| 3 | 432960 | 25.777321% |
| 4 | 132915 | 7.913416% |
| 5 | 16155 | 0.961827% |

which matches posita's results.

`result` contains the distribution of full surviving action sets (a la "player 1 is left with 3 action dice: 6, 3, 3") but the number of possible such sets grows rapidly with number of action dice (e.g. this example results in 252 rows), so I won't reproduce the table here.

[You can try the script in your browser here.](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/notebooks/lab?path=stack_exchange%2Fall_action_stress.ipynb)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much. I appreciate the notes you wrote as well; it gives all the results i was after and then some!

Answer (score 4):

My AnyDice Fu is lacking, so this is a [`dyce`](https://posita.github.io/dyce/)¹-based solution, but I believe is otherwise directly responsive and captures @Dale M's algorithmic sentiments, at least as he was able to best convey them while trapped in his airline lounge.  The slightly tricky bit with AnyDice is that you need *two* pointers (one for each of your action and stress rolls). In the alternative, you can use a proxy (e.g., popping the max value off your stress roll as you consume it).

```
from dyce import P
from dyce.p import RollT

def actions_vs_stresses(action_roll: RollT, stress_roll: RollT) -> int:
    actions_not_canceled_by_stresses = []
    # We want to walk through each roll, opportunistically canceling the best action we
    # can given our maximum unspent stress. Rolls are ordered least-to-greatest, so we
    # start at the end and walk backwards, accumulating or canceling actions as we go.
    action_index = len(action_roll) - 1
    stress_index = len(stress_roll) - 1
    while action_index >= 0:
        if stress_index >= 0 and action_roll[action_index] <= stress_roll[stress_index]:
            # We have unspent stress, and our current (max unexamined) action is
            # cancelable by our current (max unspent) stress, so we decrement both
            # counters without counting the action
            action_index -= 1
            stress_index -= 1
        else:
            # Either we're out of stresses, or our current (max unexamined) action is
            # not cancelable (i.e., greater than) our current (max unspent) stress, so
            # we count that action and decrement only the action counter, leaving any
            # unspent stress for the next iteration
            actions_not_canceled_by_stresses.append(action_roll[action_index])
            action_index -= 1
    # Uncomment the following line to see the specific rolls, but this gets
    # overwhelming pretty fast. (We accumulate uncanceled actions in order of greatest-
    # to-least, above. While not strictly necessary, we reverse their order when
    # printing for consistency with roll ordering.)
    #print(f"{action_roll} vs {stress_roll} -> {actions_not_canceled_by_stresses[::-1]}")
    return len(actions_not_canceled_by_stresses)

h = P.foreach(actions_vs_stresses, action_roll=5@P(6), stress_roll=3@P(6))
print(h.format(scaled=True))
```

Output:

```
avg |    2.44
std |    0.68
var |    0.46
  2 |  65.35% |##################################################
  3 |  25.78% |###################
  4 |   7.91% |######
  5 |   0.96% |
```

The above focuses on readability rather than efficiency. There are certainly optimizations to be had, but probably aren't worthwhile until you get into substantially larger pools.

You can play around with a more generalized version in your browser: [image: Try dyce] *[[source](https://github.com/posita/dyce-notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/stack-exchange/action-stress-198555)]*

While a matter of taste, I find [`anydyce`](https://posita.github.io/anydyce/)'s² "burst" graphs are well-suited to visualizing distributions. (Screenshot for select scenarios below.)

---

¹ `dyce` is my Python dice probability library.

² `anydyce` is my visualization layer for `dyce` meant as a rough stand-in for AnyDice.

---

[image: anydyce burst graphs]

Comment: Hey that looks like its getting somewhere. Thanks for you efforts! I'll have to dig into this a bit as I've never used Dyce but the burst charts seem to be showing.. remaining action dice, right? 2d6 v 2d6 having a nearly 50% chance to cancel both dice is the kind of information im after!

Answer (score 3):

### Anydice will not do what you want

You can certainly determine the *totals* of the remaining dice, but Anydice will not help show you each dice left - it's not designed for that.

```
function: action A:s stress S:s {
P: {}
M: 1
loop N over {1..#A} {
  if N@A > M@S {
    P: {P, N@A}
  }
  else {
    M: M+1
  }
}
result: P
}

X: 5
Y: 3
output [action Xd6 stress Yd6]
```

will give the [result](https://anydice.com/program/28f81).

However, this represents the result of \$(5+3)^6=262,144\$ individual (but not distinct) sequences. You cannot tell if, for example, a result of 10 represents 5,5 or 2,3,5 or 2,2,2,2,2 or 6,2,2 or anything else.

Comment: For pools sent to `s`-type parameters, AnyDice appears to only iterate over all sorted sequences rather than all ordered sequences. This is $$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$ per pool where \$n\$ is the pool size and \$k\$ is the number of sides per die; in this case we have $$\binom{10}{5} \binom{8}{5} = 14112$$

Comment: Also, instead of concatenating to `P` (which gets implicitly summed at the end), you can make a quasi-tuple with `P: 10 * P + N@A`, which puts one roll on each digit. This seems to be the AnyDice-ish way of doing things, given that the `@` operator extracts digits when applied to numbers. Of course, this approach starts to break down for multi-digit elements.

Comment: This is also very useful, thank you; i like having the graph view on any dice, and i can compare this to what i was using to see where i went wrong!

Answer (score 2):

[AnyDice can, in fact, do this](https://anydice.com/program/2bc14).

The tricky part, as noted in [Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198588), is indicating "how many action dice are left and what the values of those dice are", since AnyDice can only output probability distributions over numbers, not over *sequences* of numbers.  But we can get around this with a helper function that encodes a sequence as the digits of a number:

```
function: encode SEQUENCE:s in base BASE:n {
  NUMBER: 0
  loop DIGIT over SEQUENCE {
    NUMBER: BASE * NUMBER + DIGIT
  }
  result: NUMBER
}
```

For example, calling this function as `[encode {3,1,4,1,5,9} in base 10]` will return the number 314159.  Since any d6 roll fits nicely as a single base 10 digit, that works fine for our purposes here. (If you wanted to try using, say, a d12 or a d20, you could use the same encoding function, but with base 100 instead.)

With this encoding issue dealt with, we can then write our actual code. As usual, when implementing any nontrivial dice-counting mechanic in AnyDice, we need to write a function that takes a sequence parameter (or two, in this case) and let AnyDice call it for all possible rolls of a dice pool (or two):

```
function: ACTION:s action STRESS:s stress {
  \ Loop over the ACTION dice, canceling any with an equal or higher STRESS roll if possible, keep the rest.  \
  \ Note that this algorithm relies on the ACTION and STRESS sequences both being sorted in descending order! \
  KEEP: {}
  INDEX: 1  \ This index points to the first (i.e. highest) stress die not yet used. \
  loop DIE over ACTION {
    if INDEX <= #STRESS & INDEX@STRESS >= DIE {
      INDEX: INDEX + 1  \ Cancel this action die, move index to next stress die. \  
    } else {
      KEEP: {KEEP, DIE} \ Keep this action die, don't move index. \
    }
  }

  \ We cannot return a sequence from a function auto-summed over a die, so we must encode it as a number. \
  result: [encode KEEP in base 10]
}

output [5d6 action 3d6 stress]
```

This code loops over the action dice in descending numerical order (as AnyDice sorts dice pools by default), checking each one against the highest stress die not yet used.  If the stress die is equal to or higher than the action die, we let those two dice cancel out (and update the `INDEX` variable to point to the next highest stress die); if it's not, we add the uncancelled action die to the `KEEP` sequence, which we return (encoded as a number) in the end.

(Note that we don't explicitly return the number of remaining dice, since you can just read that from the number of digits in the result.)

FWIW, the output of this code, exported and reformatted as a Markdown table, looks like this:

| Remaining dice | Probability (%) |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 5.8103161675 |
| 21 | 5.81263812681 |
| 22 | 2.90602137631 |
| 31 | 3.52461515013 |
| 32 | 2.88726708962 |
| 33 | 2.06797267947 |
| 41 | 3.03819444444 |
| 42 | 1.87513098232 |
| 43 | 2.18561861759 |
| 44 | 1.96842611645 |
| 51 | 3.52461515013 |
| 52 | 1.87513098232 |
| 53 | 1.64561423563 |
| 54 | 2.36274243637 |
| 55 | 2.46740921734 |
| 61 | 5.81263812681 |
| 62 | 2.88726708962 |
| 63 | 2.18561861759 |
| 64 | 2.36274243637 |
| 65 | 3.78479366712 |
| 66 | 4.36266384697 |
| 222 | 0.339958657217 |
| 322 | 0.606388603109 |
| 332 | 0.548339620485 |
| 333 | 0.421286770309 |
| 422 | 0.392946959305 |
| 432 | 0.621570644719 |
| 433 | 0.764460448102 |
| 442 | 0.379551040238 |
| 443 | 0.70016003658 |
| 444 | 0.498090039628 |
| 522 | 0.379551040238 |
| 532 | 0.475108596251 |
| 533 | 0.560842478281 |
| 542 | 0.475108596251 |
| 543 | 0.864483310471 |
| 544 | 0.99576331733 |
| 552 | 0.392946959305 |
| 553 | 0.560842478281 |
| 554 | 0.943072702332 |
| 555 | 0.699445587563 |
| 622 | 0.548339620485 |
| 632 | 0.621570644719 |
| 633 | 0.70016003658 |
| 642 | 0.475108596251 |
| 643 | 0.864483310471 |
| 644 | 0.943072702332 |
| 652 | 0.621570644719 |
| 653 | 0.864483310471 |
| 654 | 1.46462048468 |
| 655 | 1.70396090535 |
| 662 | 0.606388603109 |
| 663 | 0.764460448102 |
| 664 | 0.99576331733 |
| 665 | 1.70396090535 |
| 666 | 1.27945911446 |
| 2222 | 0.010121361073 |
| 3222 | 0.0306617703094 |
| 3322 | 0.0428669410151 |
| 3332 | 0.027982586496 |
| 3333 | 0.028756572931 |
| 4222 | 0.0226242188691 |
| 4322 | 0.060728166438 |
| 4332 | 0.060728166438 |
| 4333 | 0.0857338820302 |
| 4422 | 0.0321502057613 |
| 4432 | 0.0571559213535 |
| 4433 | 0.119670210334 |
| 4442 | 0.0217311575979 |
| 4443 | 0.078589391861 |
| 4444 | 0.0503686556927 |
| 5222 | 0.0217311575979 |
| 5322 | 0.0500114311843 |
| 5332 | 0.048225308642 |
| 5333 | 0.0678726566072 |
| 5422 | 0.048225308642 |
| 5432 | 0.0821616369456 |
| 5433 | 0.175040009145 |
| 5442 | 0.0500114311843 |
| 5443 | 0.175040009145 |
| 5444 | 0.158071844993 |
| 5522 | 0.0321502057613 |
| 5532 | 0.048225308642 |
| 5533 | 0.0982367398262 |
| 5542 | 0.048225308642 |
| 5543 | 0.167895518976 |
| 5544 | 0.225051440329 |
| 5552 | 0.0226242188691 |
| 5553 | 0.0678726566072 |
| 5554 | 0.150034293553 |
| 5555 | 0.0854957323579 |
| 6222 | 0.027982586496 |
| 6322 | 0.060728166438 |
| 6332 | 0.0571559213535 |
| 6333 | 0.078589391861 |
| 6422 | 0.048225308642 |
| 6432 | 0.0821616369456 |
| 6433 | 0.175040009145 |
| 6442 | 0.048225308642 |
| 6443 | 0.167895518976 |
| 6444 | 0.150034293553 |
| 6522 | 0.0571559213535 |
| 6532 | 0.0821616369456 |
| 6533 | 0.167895518976 |
| 6542 | 0.0821616369456 |
| 6543 | 0.278635116598 |
| 6544 | 0.385802469136 |
| 6552 | 0.060728166438 |
| 6553 | 0.175040009145 |
| 6554 | 0.385802469136 |
| 6555 | 0.304831580552 |
| 6622 | 0.0428669410151 |
| 6632 | 0.060728166438 |
| 6633 | 0.119670210334 |
| 6642 | 0.0500114311843 |
| 6643 | 0.175040009145 |
| 6644 | 0.225051440329 |
| 6652 | 0.060728166438 |
| 6653 | 0.175040009145 |
| 6654 | 0.385802469136 |
| 6655 | 0.450102880658 |
| 6662 | 0.0306617703094 |
| 6663 | 0.0857338820302 |
| 6664 | 0.158071844993 |
| 6665 | 0.304831580552 |
| 6666 | 0.160751028807 |
| 22222 | 0.0000595374180765 |
| 32222 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 33222 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 33322 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 33332 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 33333 | 0.000476299344612 |
| 42222 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 43222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 43322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 43332 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 43333 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 44222 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 44322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 44332 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 44333 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 44422 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 44432 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 44433 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 44442 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 44443 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 44444 | 0.00160751028807 |
| 52222 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 53222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 53322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 53332 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 53333 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 54222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 54322 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 54332 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 54333 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 54422 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 54432 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 54433 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 54442 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 54443 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 54444 | 0.00803755144033 |
| 55222 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 55322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 55332 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 55333 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 55422 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 55432 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 55433 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 55442 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 55443 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 55444 | 0.0160751028807 |
| 55522 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 55532 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 55533 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 55542 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 55543 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 55544 | 0.0160751028807 |
| 55552 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 55553 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 55554 | 0.00803755144033 |
| 55555 | 0.0038103947569 |
| 62222 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 63222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 63322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 63332 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 63333 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 64222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 64322 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 64332 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 64333 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 64422 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 64432 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 64433 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 64442 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 64443 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 64444 | 0.00803755144033 |
| 65222 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 65322 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65332 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65333 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 65422 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65432 | 0.00714449016918 |
| 65433 | 0.0285779606767 |
| 65442 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65443 | 0.0285779606767 |
| 65444 | 0.0321502057613 |
| 65522 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 65532 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65533 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 65542 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 65543 | 0.0285779606767 |
| 65544 | 0.048225308642 |
| 65552 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 65553 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 65554 | 0.0321502057613 |
| 65555 | 0.0190519737845 |
| 66222 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 66322 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66332 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66333 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 66422 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66432 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 66433 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 66442 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66443 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 66444 | 0.0160751028807 |
| 66522 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66532 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 66533 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 66542 | 0.00357224508459 |
| 66543 | 0.0285779606767 |
| 66544 | 0.048225308642 |
| 66552 | 0.0017861225423 |
| 66553 | 0.0142889803384 |
| 66554 | 0.048225308642 |
| 66555 | 0.038103947569 |
| 66622 | 0.000595374180765 |
| 66632 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 66633 | 0.00476299344612 |
| 66642 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 66643 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 66644 | 0.0160751028807 |
| 66652 | 0.00119074836153 |
| 66653 | 0.00952598689224 |
| 66654 | 0.0321502057613 |
| 66655 | 0.038103947569 |
| 66662 | 0.000297687090383 |
| 66663 | 0.00238149672306 |
| 66664 | 0.00803755144033 |
| 66665 | 0.0190519737845 |
| 66666 | 0.00744217725956 |

Of course, if you're only interested in some specific property of the results (like the number of kept dice, or the value of the highest kept die), you don't have to go through this whole table adding up the probabilities.  Instead, just modify the AnyDice code to return that property directly (e.g. with `result: #KEEP` or `result: 1@KEEP`) and re-run it.